# How to Get request body in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there a way I can extract the request body (JSON) from the spring cloud gateway?.  I went through a few approaches like RequestBodyrewrite and all, but as far as I understood it is used for modifying the response body. In my case, I wanted to get the request body and do some logic there and send the data via headers to the underlying microservices. Right now I am getting the request body with the attribute "cachedRequestBodyObject" with the help of the request body predicator.

```
readBody(SomeClass.class, s-> true)
```

I don't think I am not fully making use of the request body predicator here. We would also get this as part of the getRequestBody() method but it has a data buffer as a return type, so not sure how to get the JSON details from the data buffer. Is there a way better approach to do this ?..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi,
your approach works, but typically the readBody is a predicate to allow you to have a rule to modify the destination based on the request input body.
Another solution it's to create your own filter only to cache the request body and after that you are able to use them in other filter to manipulate the header with the logic which you want.
Please be aware that you only want to invoke the filter to read body once, because if you have other places with this you'll start having memory leaks.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? How to did you get body of every requests?